# JOLT: Merge specific data from JSON array using id key and leave other arrays untouch without "recursivelySquashNulls"

Tags: arrays, json, null, jolt

I have been struggling with this problem for a couple of weeks now, been getting tons of help from everyone here but I come to another stopper in my current quest to solve this puzzle.

I previously have this issue of merging data into another one to avoid duplicates and make a cleaner version of the JSON but in my current platform version I CAN'T use recursivelySquashNulls and the JOLT without that loses it's format.
My Input

```json
{
  "clubhouse": [
    {
      "id": "01",
      "statusId": "ok",
      "stateid": "2",
      "nationalities": [
        {
          "nationalityid": "1"
        },
        {
          "nationalityid": "2"
        },
        {
          "nationalityid": "3"
        }
      ],
      "TypeId": "3"
    },
    {
      "id": "01",
      "investors": [
        {
          "investor": {
            "id": "1234",
            "gender": "01"
          },
          "inamount": "1500000",
          "ratio": "12"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "01",
      "investors": [
        {
          "investor": {
            "id": "4321",
            "gender": "02"
          },
          "inamount": "1700000",
          "ratio": "12"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "02",
      "statusId": "ok",
      "stateid": "2",
      "nationalities": [
        {
          "nationalityid": "3"
        },
        {
          "nationalityid": "4"
        },
        {
          "nationalityid": "5"
        }
      ],
      "TypeId": "3"
    },
    {
      "id": "02",
      "investors": [
        {
          "investor": {
            "id": "1333",
            "gender": "01"
          },
          "inamount": "1500000",
          "ratio": "12"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "03",
      "statusId": "ok",
      "stateid": "5",
      "nationalities": [
        {
          "nationalityid": "3"
        },
        {
          "nationalityid": "4"
        },
        {
          "nationalityid": "5"
        }
      ],
      "TypeId": "3"
    },
    {
      "id": "03",
      "investors": [
        {
          "investor": {
            "id": "",
            "gender": ""
          },
          "inamount": "",
          "ratio": ""
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "02",
      "statusId": "ok",
      "stateid": "2",
      "nationalities": [
        {
          "nationalityid": "3"
        },
        {
          "nationalityid": "4"
        },
        {
          "nationalityid": "5"
        }
      ],
      "TypeId": "3"
    },
    {
      "id": "02",
      "investors": [
        {
          "investor": {
            "id": "1334",
            "gender": "02"
          },
          "inamount": "1900000",
          "ratio": "12"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

The JOLT I have right now (no recursivelySquashNull)

```json
[
  {
    // group by "id" values to create separate objects 
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "*": "@(1,id).&",
          "nationalities": {
            "*": {
              "@": "@(3,id).&2[&3][]"
            }
          },
          "investors": {
            "*": {
              "*": {
                "@": "@(4,id).&3[&4].&"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    // pick only the first components from the repeated values populated within the arrays 
    "operation": "cardinality",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": "ONE",
        "investors": "MANY",
        // Have to add nationalities here, if not it only shows null in the second array since the real values are hidden behind
        "nationalities": "MANY"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    // get rid of object labels
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": ""
    }
  }
]
```

My desire output

```json
{
  "clubhouse": [
    {
      "id": "01",
      "statusId": "ok",
      "stateid": "2",
            "nationalities": [
        {
          "nationalityid": "1"
        },
        {
          "nationalityid": "2"
        },
        {
          "nationalityid": "3"
        }
      ],
      "TypeId": "3",
      "investors": [
        {
          "investor": {
            "id": "1234",
            "gender": "01"
          },
          "inamount": "1500000",
          "ratio": "12"
        },
        {
          "investor": {
            "id": "4321",
            "gender": "02"
          },
          "inamount": "1700000",
          "ratio": "12"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "02",
      "statusId": "ok",
      "stateid": "2",
      "nationalities": [
        {
          "nationalityid": "3"
        },
        {
          "nationalityid": "4"
        },
        {
          "nationalityid": "5"
        }
      ],
      "TypeId": "3",
      "investors": [
        {
          "investor": {
            "id": "1333",
            "gender": "01"
          },
          "inamount": "1500000",
          "ratio": "12"
        },
        {
          "investor": {
            "id": "1334",
            "gender": "02"
          },
          "inamount": "1900000",
          "ratio": "12"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "03",
      "statusId": "ok",
      "stateid": "5",
      "nationalities": [
        {
          "nationalityid": "3"
        },
        {
          "nationalityid": "4"
        },
        {
          "nationalityid": "5"
        }
      ],
      "TypeId": "3",
      "investors": [
        {
          "investor": {
            "id": "",
            "gender": ""
          },
          "inamount": "",
          "ratio": ""
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: What if `"nationalities"` array for common id values differ? (eg. as an example: if the array has nationalityid values 1,2,3 for the first id = 01, while 4,5,3 for thsecond object with id = 01) ...

Comment: That's not possible since we have created conditions for that in the DB.

Comment: I was able to clean the input a little bit to avoid unnecessary data, still no luck with the JOLT transformation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use wrapper square brackets for ampersand symbol in order to get rid of null components occur within arrays. For this, apply **shift** transformation twice for `"nationalities"` array, and change **cardinality** spec as below such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "*": "@(1,id).&",
          "nationalities": {
            "*": {
              "*": {
                "@": "@(4,id).&3[&2].&"
              }
            }
          },
          "investors": { // first time
            "*": {
              "*": "@(3,id).&2.&3.&"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "cardinality",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": "ONE",
        "nationalities": {
          "*": {
            "*": "ONE"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": "&1.&",
        "inv*": { // second time
          "*": {
            "@": "&3.&2"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    // get rid of object labels of "id" values
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": ""
    }
  }
]
```